# остановить скипт php из ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

реализую progress-bar выполнения скрипта в пхп. По кнопке старт запускаю скрипт пхп аяксом и получаю данные о прогрессе. Далее нужно по нажатию на другую кнопку остановить выполнение скрипта пхп. как остановить выполнение скипта php из ajax?

Comment: например, напишите в сессию "стоп". а в основном скрипте проверяйте

Comment: @splash58 можно по подробнее? не совсем понятно

Comment: ajax вызывает скрипт на сервере, он пишет сигнал, что нужно остановиться, основной скрипт в цикле проверяет наличие такого сигнала и прекращается, как обнаруживает.

Comment: @splash58, так?
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['stop']))$_SESSION['stop']=0;if($_POST['stop'])$_SESSION['stop']=1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{   if($_SESSION['stop']){$_SESSION['stop']=0;break;}
    $_SESSION['progress'] = $i * 10; 
    session_write_close();
    sleep(1);
}
exit();

Comment: как-то, наверное, так